# How to run "git log filename" using libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I can't find any options to specify a filename in git_revwalk_new/git_revwalk_push, then how can I retrieve all revisions for a specified file?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to find inspiration from the [log.c example](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/examples/log.c) in libgit2.

More precisely, you'll need to perform the revwalk normally, and [perform the path filtering](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/examples/log.c#L119) using [git_pathspec_match_tree](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/pathspec/git_pathspec_match_tree) on each commit's tree.