Get a file's commit history with Rugged
I would like to use Rugged to get the commit history of a file, similar to what git log <filename> produces. But I can't seem to find a direct way to do this in the Rugged API. Perhaps I am overlooking it?
The best way I have found of doing it is by using a Rugged Walker:
walker = Rugged::Walker.new(repository)
walker.push(repository.head.target.oid)
history = []
walker.each do |commit|
  commit.diff.each_delta do |delta|
    history.push(some_commit_info) if delta.new_file[:path] == file_path
  end
end

Is there a more direct way of achieving this, rather than by taking this low level approach?

I am not familiar with the library so I hesitate to "answer" but it seems like given your code and a short trip through the source it seems like you could use walker = repo.walk(repository.head.target.oid) to at least cleanup the first part. It seems that "walking" is the only appropriate way to get a diff history on a file basis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112803/how-to-run-git-log-filename-using-libgit2 It seems other libraries have a nicer interface for querying commits (C# for Example repo.Commits.QueryBy("file_name")) but I don't see this in rugged
